# Updating Mongoose Subdocument collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose Schema's defined...

```
var BlogSchema = new Schema({
    content: String,
    comments:[CommentSchema], //embed the comments
    owner: {type: ObjectId , ref: 'User'}
})


var CommentSchema = new Schema({
   commentContent : String,
   commentPostTime : Number,
   likes :  [{type: ObjectId , ref: 'User'}],
   likeCount: {type: Number, default:0}
})

var UserSchema = new Schema({


})
```

When a user likes a comment. The user should be added to likes list and the embedded Comment Subdocument in Blog Document should be updated. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As your UserSchema doesn't contain much information, it's probably simplest if you don't try to fake a join through Mongoose's population feature.  Using MongoDB by itself, accomplishing this would be done with a single operation.  Below, I'm just storing the "_id" field of some user document that I want to reference.

```
> var userID = userdoc._id;
> db.comments.update( { _id : commentID }, 
              { $push : { likes : userID } } );
```

Doing this with Mongoose would require you to change your schema slightly:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
   commentContent : String,
   commentPostTime : Number,
   likes :  [ObjectId],
   likeCount: {type: Number, default:0}
})
```

Then, you could just add the new user to the list of likes and increment the likeCount field with the following query:

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate( commentID, { $push : { likes : "samantha" }, $inc : { likeCount : 1 } } );
```

Is this better than using Mongoose population?  Handling your data this way will take an extra step when you look up users from comments.  First, you'll have to grab the userID from the list of likes in the comment, then you'll have to run a separate query to get that user's document.  However, since your use case doesn't appear to require looking anything up in the user documents, this approach should work well for you.  Performance-wise, I believe that this two-step process is what Mongoose is doing under the hood anyway with their population method.  Personally, I'm fine with the extra lookup step in exchange for more control over my data.